# Controlling WS2812b LED strip produces inconsistent and uncontrollable output

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, rpi.gpio, led, ws2812

## Background

I'm trying to control a single WS2812b LED strip from a Raspberry Pi. I've followed [this tutorial](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connect-control-raspberry-pi-ws2812-rgb-led-strips/) from raspberrypi.com (with the exception of Prep & Installation step 4, because I couldn't find `snd-blacklist.conf`).

That didn't work, so I also tried [this tutorial](https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/ws2812-addressable-leds-raspberry-pi-quickstart-guide.html) (which involved adding a Logic Level converter), and when that didn't improve things, a few other tutorials/videos, all to no avail.

## Code & Output

The first tutorial got the closest. It had me use [this github library](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x), where I eventually ran `strandtest.py`. It appeared to partially work, but not entirely. I wasn't sure (and I'm still not) if this is a hardware or software issue, so I reduced the code to the minimum possible where it still turns on at least one LED.

```py
import time
from rpi_ws281x import *

LED_COUNT      = 14      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255     # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
strip.begin()

while True:
    print ('Running display')
    for j in range(100):
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, Color(50, 50, 50))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(.05)
```

Yes, those nested loops are necessary. Simplifying to something like this without loops doesn't turn on any LEDs at all:

```py
strip.setPixelColor(0, Color(100, 100, 100))
strip.show()
time.sleep(10)
```

**Demo Video**

When I run that code (the first block), this is what happens:
https://youtu.be/nzMCeyBNY50

Every time I run the code, I wait a few seconds, and eventually some LEDs turn on. It's different every time: sometimes a couple turn on, sometimes all of them, sometimes they turn off again for a little bit as it keeps running, etc. This was true even before I switched to using the Logic Level converter from the second tutorial, and happens the same way even if I run the original `strandtest.py`.

## Parts

I've followed this schematic from the second tutorial linked above. Note that **I'm powering 14 LEDs** currently (but would like to do the full strip in the future). Also, this schematic shows the power for the LEDs running through the breadboard, but I've soldered the red power+ directly instead.

[image: schematic from core-electronics.com]

Here's a list of the parts I used:

- Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (already owned)
- Breadboard, miscellaneous wires, and solder (already owned)
- [Logic Level converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LG646VS)
- [WS2812b RGB LED strip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BKNS7DJ) (5 meters, 30/m)
- [5V 10A Power Supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CMM2BBR)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! I am sorry to say you are light on the 50 watt (5 * 10 = 50) power supply, here is why: (Ohm's law states volts * amps = watts). Your Pi needs about 3 amps or 15 watts. You now have 7 amps or 35 Watts remaining. Next you have 5 meters of leds at 18 watts per meter (per your link) so that is (18 * 5) 75 watts. You had 35 watts left after the Pi so you are at a negative 40 watts or -8 amps. Best solution get another power supply and if you use both be sure to connect the grounds of each together and to the Pi ground.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation of the wiring must have been unclear: the pi is powered through the USB port by a standard AC to USB converter, completely separate from the power to the LEDs. I measured the led circuit and it was hitting about 4.8 V (what I'd expect), but it was hardly drawing 1 amp, because I'm only using 14 LEDs and they aren't even fully lit. (Note that I will use more LEDs later if I get this working, and may have to change the power supply).

Comment: One thing I did notice was that the data line was barely at .1 volts (with or without the logic level converter). I thought the pi was supposed to be sending 3.3 V which I would increase to 5 V, but unless I'm measuring poorly (which is definitely a possibility) then the voltage is very low.

Comment: Schematics generally tell more than pages of words!

Comment: @kviLL please edit your question and explain how the LEDs and Pi are being powered.

Comment: I had included a link to a schematic from one of the tutorials I followed. I've edited the post now to embed the image directly instead, so hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: Frizzy things do not count as schematics. Your Pi will not work it does not have any power. Show it exactly how you have it wired and the test points you used to measure voltage and what you used to measure it.

Comment: The pi is powered by a USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same problem.

If `/etc/modprobe.d/snd-blacklist.conf` does not exist, you need to create it and add the following line

`blacklist snd_bcm2835`

You may also need to add/uncomment the following from `/boot/config.txt`

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_force_edid_audio=1
```

Don't forget to reboot and all should work nicely.